# Как правильно работать с ветками git

Tags: git

Использую git и периодически забываю создать новую ветку (считаем что ветка нужна).
Пишу какую-то часть кода, и когда вспоминаю о том что нужно было сначала создать новую ветку, а потом в ветке уже писать код - получается приходится делать много действий делать лишних:

- удалять написанный код (файлы и папки)
- создавать ветку
- создавать заново файлы и папки, вставлять написанный код

Есть ли какой-то простой способ не делать лишних действий - а как то указать git что нужно создать ветку, переключится на нее и все что было создано перенести?

Comment: Ветка — это всего лишь указатель на коммит. Не имеет никакого значения, когда вы создаёте ветку — до или после написания кода, результат будет один и тот же

Comment: Спасибо, не правильно понял работу git - думал всё более строго работает и в момент создания ветки - изменения удалятся, если не были добавлены.

Comment: Единственный момент, который может смутить — если вы не создали ветку заранее, то вместе с новыми коммитами будет сдвигаться и текущая активная ветка. И когда вы обнаружите, что вы забыли создать ветку, придётся передвинуть текущую активную ветку на тот коммит, на который она должна указывать и указывала до внесённых вами изменений (но в изменении ветки тоже ничего сложного нет)

Comment: Я до коммита вспоминаю об этом, но понял да, что можно и тут еще накосячить...

Comment: В случае такого конфуза (если изменения еще не были запушены), можно создать новую ветку и после создания коммита (тогда она будет указывать на этот коммит, как будто бы коммит был создан после создания и переключения на эту ветку), а старую ветку (с которой забыл переключиться) перенести обратно на тот коммит, где она была до внесения всех этих изменений (делайте `checkout` коммита, затем `branch -f` чтобы переставить указатель нужной ветки).

Comment: Как раз хотел попросить команду, но вы дополнили, спасибо - теперь понял как делать в таких случаях.

Answer (score 0):

1. Создать новую ветку на текущем коммите.
2. «Перемотать» ветку в которой ошибочно велась работа назад на коммит, от которого должна была начинаться текущая ветка.

Второе можно выполнить как `git branch --force <имя ветки> <коммит куда переместить>`

Comment: Я про коммиты ничего не писал.
Но если вы хотите именно как ответ зафиксировать - то лучше 2 варианта разобрать - которые выше разобраны в комментариях.